Tiktok v2 API request parameter type is incorrect
I'm encountering an issue with the Creator Query Info endpoint. I've followed all the instructions specified in the Tiktok API docs but keep receiving an error.

invalid_params - The request parameter type is incorrect. Status 400

Here's the code I'm using:
$request = new PendingRequest();
$res = $request->withHeaders([
    'Authorization'       => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
])->post('https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/creator_info/query/');

Are there any required parameters? According to the documentation, it only requires Headers. The auth token endpoint works fine, and I receive the correct token (https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/oauth/token/).

If the token is indeed valid (and you've checked that with the curl example provided in the docs or Postman or whatever), my educated guess is, that you need to tell the PendingRequest object how to format the body (JSON in this case). Try $request->asJson(). Alternatively add the second parameter to ->post (which is the payload) as '{}'.

I realise this is an old problem, but I had the exact same issue and spent hours trying to fix it.
As far as I can tell it has something to do with the default headers that Laravel / Guzzle send. Creating a basic cURL request with just the two headers works fine. The other option is to create your own Request from scratch with Guzzle, something like:
        // Step 1 - Query creator info, this is an obligatory step for some reason...
        $handlerStack = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create(new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler());

        // Create the client with the custom handler
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $handlerStack]);

        // Create a request without the Content-Length header
        $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
            'POST', 
            'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/creator_info/query/', 
            [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->social_account->access_token->access_token,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept' => '*/*',
            ]
        );

        $response = $client->send($request);

So far everything seems to work fine now. As to why TikTok is so picky about headers? I have no idea.
Edit - After some tinkering, I've found that setting the POST body to null (not an empty string, but actual null) also seems to work, something like:
$response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $social_account->access_token->access_token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept' => '*/*',
    ])
    ->withOptions(['debug' => true])
    ->post('https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/creator_info/query/', null);

